# Remove changes by specific user in git

Tags: git, git-revert

This is what our commit network looks like:

Each color represents commits by a different user.
The two commits I've labelled works, are the last commits to work.

[image]

Is there a way to revert all the red commits up to the time green working commit?

In way to revert to the working green commit, and then "replay" every commit since, but choose not to "replay" the commits by the red user?

Comment: not with the default git commands, you can rebuild that branch with a script, doing the commands for you, but even so, I would expect some conflicts along the way. It's not going to be a walk on the park.

Comment: We ended up reverting, cherry picking the individual commits we wanted in order(didn't cherry pick any of the merges), creating a branch (workingmaster), renaming master to oldmaster, and then renaming workingmaster to master, and to be safe just deleted our local copies and recloned it...